# Ordenação de objetos em um Json sem id no Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

Como posso ordenar a exibição de um array de objetos de um Json no Angular, `ng-repeat`? `orderBy`? sendo que esse json não possui nenhum *id* para fazer essa ordenação, gostaria de poder ordena-lo por sequencia de "ultimo adicionado".

Answer (score 1):

O melhor jeito é usar um recurso do Angular chamado "filter", ele permite que você manipule um valor, você pode usar o "order by" pra isso, algo do tipo :

```
{{item in items | orderby : 'date' }}
```

Aqui segue um tópico do StackOverflow sobre o assunto:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261348/descending-order-by-date-filter-in-angularjs

Comment: Sim guilherme, eu entendi sobre isso, o problema é que não tenho elementos como ID ou DATA nessa api. Tenho apenas os dados, se eu ordenar por nome ou por outro elemento não terei o resultado de "ultimos adicionados". Preciso de um meio de ordenar por registro, mas não possuo nenhuma marcação pra isso...

Comment: @FábioDuarte se sua ordem de inserção for a ordem do JSON vc pode criar um filtro simplesmente pedindo pra inverter!

Answer (score 0):

Como o [Guilherme falou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75068/41113), você pode utilizar os filtros que o próprio AngularJS te oferece. Mas, considerando que você não parece possuir nenhum atributo dentro do seu JSON que possa ser utilizado diretamente para fazer essa ordenação, talvez seja melhor criar seu próprio filtro de ordenação:

```
app.filter('meuFiltroOrdenarPor', function(){
    return function(array, atributo) {
        // sua função de sort para ordenar o "array" considerando "atributo"
        return array;
    }
});
```

e para chamá-lo no HTML:

```
{{seuObjetoJSON | meuFiltroOrdenarPor}}
```

Entretanto, se você precisa ordernar por "último adicionado", não vejo uma forma de resolver isso que não envolva colocar esse atributo em seu JSON, fazer com que todo objeto tenha tal atributo.

Ajudaria bastante se você pudesse colocar um exemplo do JSON com o qual você está lidando.

---

**Referências**:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy